# On Serre's condition and singular locus of determinantal rings

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay-rings, determinantal-ideals

Let $R$ be a Commutative Noetherian ring. Let $\mathbf X:=[X_{ij}]_{1\le i \le r, 1 \le s \le t}$ be a matrix of indeterminates. Let $t>1$ be an  integer, and $I_t(\mathbf X)$ denote the ideal in $R[\mathbf X]$ generated by the minors of $\mathbf X$. Note that $I_t(X)=0$ if $t>\min (r,s )$.

My question is: If $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay and regular in co-dimension $2$, then is $R[\mathbf X]/I_t(X)$ also Cohen-Macaulay and regular in co-dimension  $2$ ? When can we say $R[\mathbf X]/I_t(X)$ satisfies  Serre's condition ($S_3$)?

I would also appreciate any references discussing Serre's conditions ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%27s_criterion_for_normality) and singular locus of determinantal rings as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should follow from the "relative Serre conditions" investigated in EGA IV_3, Sections 6 and 12.  I will try to track down a precise reference.

Comment: @JasonStarr: thanks for your comment here and on my other question as well. I look forward to hearing more from you ...

Comment: The precise citation is Corollaire 6.3.5(ii) in EGA IV_2 (which is an immediate corollary of the more fundamental result, Proposition 6.3.1).

Comment: @JasonStarr: please feel free to put them as answers, I'll accept it :)